# Maintaining view state when navigating to another view

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have one VuesJS view with two components in it that have a `main-detail` relationship. The user can click on an item in the `main` component (the item gets highlighted) and the `details` component will show the related detail items.

```
products.vue

<main></main>
<details>></details>
```

The user can edit a detail item and I want that to take place using a separate view containing the necessary components to edit the detail item.

I want the user to be able to navigate back to the `products.vue` view (say after finishing the editing process) with its state as it was when the initiated the editing operation.

I tried wrapping each of `main` and `details` in `<keep-alive></keep-alive>` but that did not seem to do the trick.

I have also read a few posts where `<keep-alive></keep-alive>` is used with the `include` property around the `<router-view></router-view>` but I'm not sure what to include in the `include` in my case.

Any thoughts on whether this is possible or what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To persist state beyond route changes the state needs to either be stored:

1. in a component that is a parent to the `<router-view>` (such as `<App>`)
2. in a [new vue instance with shared state](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) that you import into the required components
3. in the [official state management library Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) **(recommended)**

Comment: could you elaborate on #1? Also, storing state is pretty easy the issue is that in cases like mine, some UI state such as the page the user is on (in multipage list of items) and the scroll position in a list are not simple to restore unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Shouldn't #3 be Pinia?